# Accepting the mod agreement in Channels doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

To use moderator functions within a Channel, you also need to accept a moderator agreement for the Channel.

This is all well and good, except that the button to accept the agreement leaves you at a 404 page.

The button is technically a `<form>` that points to an `action` of a raw `/admin` link rather than a `/c/channel/admin` link.

Comment: Might be related to this bug: https://i.imgur.com/UXPz04y.png I guess I can't use this button, because I didn't accept the agreement yet

Comment: So that's where the cool kids are lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mod agreement is no longer required for Teams.